# Vista Explorer Customization

Tags: windows-vista

I'm running Windows Vista and in my Music folder, the following items appear:

- Song Name
- Artist
- Album
- ## (song # on Album)
- Genre
- Rating

I know how to remove the Rating column and substitute it with the Bit rate column. However the change only appears in the folder I changed it in.

How do I do this so this so that the Rating column is always displyed when I'm in my Music folder?

Answer (score 2):

Customize your music folder the way you like it. Then go to **Organize**, **Folder and search options**, **View**, **Use for all folders**. This should apply the current setting for all folders of the same type (all music folders).

Answer (score 0):

Click on Organize > Layout > Menu Bar
Now, click on View, then Choose Details

This should let you customize the columns as you see fit now.  It shouldn't go away after you set it, but I haven't found any setting that will propagate the change to subfolders.  You might have to do them manually.